# Jquery ajax fileupload via php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload

i have a problem with my php fileupload which im using via ajax in jquery.

This is my code in the php upload file:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"termine.csv");
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
```

This is my jquery ajax statement:

```
 $('#upload_csv').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/playground/php/updatedates.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('form#csv').serialize(),
    }).done(function(txt) {
            if(txt!='')alert(txt);
    });
});
```

and this is my form in the index.php file:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="csv" method="POST">
            <div style="float:left">
            <input name="file" type="file" id="file" size="100">
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" id="upload_csv" value="upload csv file">
            </div>
        </form>
```

The only error message i get is "error" and nothing else.

Hope somebody can help.

Comment: Please change js line like this data: $('#csv').serialize(),

Comment: @Elby There's no difference between `$('#csv')` and `$('form#csv')` if `#csv` is a form (which it is)

Comment: @iliketocodenstuff Please create a else part if(txt!='')alert(txt); else alert("HERE"); Let me know what is the result

Comment: @Elby the alert("here") isn't executed.

Comment: that means error in your updatedates.php or nothing to get in $_FILE  so please comment all  other codes in that echo any this and check should you get any any result in alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$().serialize` always creates a `url-encoded` string, and ignores file input. You have to use another approach. See: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

One option is to put the form in a hidden `iframe` and trigger the submit event.

Also take a look at the jQuery File Upload plugin: http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: I made it without using ajax and redirect from the uploadfile.php back to the index.
This is "uglier", but simple.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: @iliketocodenstuff Have you looked at the plugin? It looks very easy to use and it uses the `iframe` method as a fallback internally.